# White screen displays for a while, when back button pressed in android

Tags: android-layout, android-intent, android, android-navigation

I have used Black theme for my android application, and I don't understand why I am getting a white screen instead if I press the back button. Can anybody tell me why this is happening?

```
 <application
    android:name="com.sample.ApplicationClass"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Below is my style defination

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:progressBarStyleHorizontal">@style/ProgressBarAppTheme</item>
    <item name="android:seekBarStyle">@style/SeekBarAppTheme</item>
</style>

  <!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>
<!-- CUSTOM SEEK BAR THEME -->
<style name="SeekBarAppTheme" parent="android:Widget.SeekBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/apptheme_scrubber_progress_horizontal_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/apptheme_scrubber_progress_horizontal_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">13dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">13dip</item>
    <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/apptheme_scrubber_control_selector_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:thumbOffset">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">16dip</item>
</style>

<!-- CUSTOM PROGRESS BAR THEME -->
<style name="ProgressBarAppTheme" parent="android:Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/apptheme_progress_horizontal_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/apptheme_progress_indeterminate_horizontal_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">16dip</item>
</style>
```

Below is my apps screenshot
[image]

Comment: Without showing anything how can we help you? Post your manifest file.

Comment: Have you handled onPause() and onResume() methods?

Comment: @AdamShort Yes i have overridden onPause() and onResume() methods and these include AsyncTask calls.

Comment: Can you post your progresbarapptheme and seekbarapp theme styles?

Comment: @AdamShort: I have edited my source code, and i observed this issue comes on Samsung devices like Galaxy SII and S4

Comment: I dont think this is to do with your themes if its black to begin with. Check you code and possibly implement onBackPressed()

Comment: @AdamShort- I have already implemented onBackPressed() method in that i have just finished the current activity.